# How to resolve/print out list of symbols in iPhone static library?

Tags: iphone

How to resolve/print out list of symbols in iPhone static library ?

I am fairly new to iPhone dev.  So my apologies if this is a trivial question.

Any tools in Windows/RHEL4(5) Linux which will be able to retrieve the
symbol table given the iPhone static library

I would be building different versions of libraries (projects) for distribution.
on Windows and Linux Servers. I would like to run a script before somebody
tries to download which would show the symbol table of the static library,
so that they can

I tried different combination of objdump, nm --target= on a library.a created
with iPhone4 SDK but all failed.

If I need to move to Ubuntu or someother distribution of server that is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but if it requires printing lib symbols `nm` is likely the utility to help you do it. `man nm` for usage.